# Зачем нужно _ в сеттере, если проперти уже существует?

Tags: javascript

Вот у меня простой класс

```
 class Person {
  constructor(fullName, birthYear) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
  }

  set fullName(name) {
    if (name.includes(' ')) this._fullName = name;
    else alert(`${name} is not a full name!`);
  }

  get fullName() {
    return this._fullName;
  }
}

const jonas = new Person('Jonas Mariano', 1996);
console.log(jonas);
```

Никак не могу понять, зачем нужно Naming Convention с _ если проперти уже существует. Мы ведь, вместо того, чтобы установить новое значение, просто создаем новую переменную в объекте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Был бы крайне благодарен за доходчивое объяснение.

Comment: очевидно, если ты будешь писать this.fullName без подчёркивания то будет вызываться сеттер, а он будет вызывать сам себя бесконечно

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Возможно, я очень туплю на ночь, а что заставляет сеттер бесконечно вызывать себя в этом случае?

Comment: Я же написал выше. fullName без подчёркивания - название сеттера, если он внутри себя тоже будет вызвать fullName значит он будет вызывать сам себя